# Python CGI like php (<?python >

Tags: python, cgi

Hey I was wondering if there's a way that I can write html and include a  and have python scripts executed when people open a page and pass POST variables to the scripts like php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mod_python`](http://modpython.org/) on apache, it allows you to embed python into HTML on apache servers., a lot like php.

Comment: Great thanks, is there a way to use it with node.js or is it just for apache?

Answer (score 0):

There is one ([Python Server Pages](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pythonapi.html#module-psp)), but it's incredibly outdated and awful.  Don't use it.

Learn to use a modern web development framework for Python, like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). They have a different way of doing things that makes the syntax you're describing unnecessary.

Comment: Sweet thanks! I'm sorry Iv never used a web framework, but is django something I could use along with node.js or is it the whole web server deal?

Comment: It's not something you could use with node.js, as it's not Javascript (this is kind of a good thing!), but there are a number of ways you can deploy it, either alone or through a web server. Read the documentation! It's really good.